# Seed Mechanism does not work fine for BlackBerry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, aes, random-seed

I have created AES key in java using seed mechanism and the same thing using BlackBerry.
My input string for Seed is same in both of these case. But I am getting different AES. But the created AES key should be same.

Is there any online help for creating AES key using seed mechanism for BlackBerry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi seed mechanism in java and blackberry are not same.
so u will never get same result in java and blackberry. so better create a key by yourself and send to blackberry users. they will use the key.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Comment: thanks, It worked great. Your comment was useful to me. I got success.

Answer (score 1):

You have already [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915786/how-to-write-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-encryption-and-decryption-with-initialization-v). The answer I gave there is still the best way. I am using what is documented there to pass data between the Blackberry and a Java server program encrypted with AES. Works fine provided you follow the API documentation on each side.