# How to write AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding encryption and decryption with Initialization Vector Parameter for BlackBerry

Tags: encryption, blackberry, aes

How to write a BlackBerry program for AES/CBC with Initialization Parameter ecncryption and Decryption
and this encryption and decryption should work independent on Programming language
Ex= If I encrypt some data using BlackBery I must be able to decrypt the same data using Java Program.

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CBCEngine allows you upto 16 bytes for across platform. so donot use CBC. try to use the default supported cipher engine.

I think ECB will be great if you use.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar sahoo

Comment: Raw ECB is NOT recommended for usage for encryption of data because of some weaknesses.

Answer (score 1):

The decryption half of your question is answered here: [decrypting data with AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding using blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901251/decrypting-data-with-aes-cbc-pkcs5padding-using-blackberry)

It should be easy to figure out encryption using the same pattern (use Encryptor instead of Decryptor engines, etc).

Comment: The link tells to use bouncy castle. Its an external jar we can not use external jar. So is there any other way to achieve this.

Comment: My answer to that question is about the BlackBerry API - sorry, I can see where that wasn't clear, I edited the first sentence to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: Hi Anthony, I tried in the way you have mentioned. But I can encrypt or decrypt upto 16 bytes means 128 bits. So If I increase the block size then i am getting error because of CBC.
I have inserted block size as multiple of 16.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this KB article? http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800779/How_to_-_Use_Basic_Encryption.html?nodeid=800640&vernum=0

You will also need to use net.rim.device.api.crypto.CBCEncryptorEngine on top of the AESEncryptorEngine (and similar for decryption).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you write your own code for AES algorithm and CBC mode, it is quite simple, around some hundreds of code lines. And, there should be reference implementation in Java language.